# Проблема с update документа через google docs api - пустой файл после обновления

Tags: php, curl, google-docs, google-docs-api

Бьюсь с google docs api. Пытаюсь обновить существующий документ на google docs.
Юзаю php и curl (Zend Framework не юзаю), основываюсь на классе `gdata.class.php` (*@author Yassine Oussi darkinux@gmail.com*).

Предварительно <s>изучил</s> зазубрил уже [документацию](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#UpdatingDocsAndFiles), пытаюсь делать правильно, через resumable protocol.

**Проблема: Обновление файла частично работает (файл plain/text). Стирание предыдущего контента производится, а вот запись нового нет.**

В соответствии с мануалом я делаю PUT-запрос (initial request)
на адрес

```
http://docs.google.com/feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full/document%3A123456789...
```

Все поля как указано, Etag документа указываю. Тело запроса оставляю пустым.
В ответ получаю код состояния 200 ok и адрес для продолжения в теге Location (unique upload URI):

```
Location: http://docs.google.com/feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full/document%3A123456789?upload_id=EnB2Uob7DWcFVJTX3oF8sdVv9koZTHacngmM_...
```

**Далее мистика**

Если на полученный урл отправляю тело файла и заголовки

```
[0] => Content-Length: 6
[1] => Content-Range: bytes 0-5/6
[2] => Content-Type: text/plain
```

То получаю в ответ

```
HTTP/1.1 308 Resume Incomplete
```

При этом заголовка `Range` в ответе нет хотя Гугл говорит, что должен быть.

Если на полученный урл отправляю тело файла и заголовки

```
[0] => Content-Length: 6
[1] => Content-Type: text/plain
```

То получаю в ответ заголовок

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

И в теле atom+xml.

**В первом случае целевой файл не меняется.**

**Во втором случае целевой файл становится пустым.**

`curl_getinfo` при этом не зависимо от размера файла показывает

```
[size_upload] => 5
```

Т.е. насколько я понимаю, ни черта не передается.

**Буду рад любому совету.**

Comment: @Город Удалось ли вам справиться с этой проблемой? Помогите разобраться!

Comment: @Пень, увы все застыло на мертвой точке тогда. Теперь вы вот напомнили, попытаюсь сегодня еще раз, свежим так сказать глазом. В случае новой информации, апну тему.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, вы забыли установить параметр для загрузки файла методом HTTP PUT для сеанса CURL?

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
```

Подробнее [здесь](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php).